# Properties with and without sugar

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators, accessor

Please don't laugh. I am desperate.

Here is a canonical example of a python class with a getter and a setter (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessor_method#Python_example)):

```
class Student(object):
    # Initializer
    def __init__(self, name):
        # An instance variable to hold the student's name
        self._name = name

    # Getter method
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    # Setter method
    @name.setter
    def name(self, new_name):
        self._name = new_name
```

Now my version without decorators:

```
class Student(object):
    # Initializer
    def __init__(self, name):
        # An instance variable to hold the student's name
        self._name = name

    # Getter method
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    name=property(fget=name)

    # Setter method
    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self._name = new_name
    name = property(fset=set_name)
```

... except that the second version just does not work. If we instatiate the Student class, e.g. `Bob=Student('Bob')`, Bob.name throws AttributeError:unreadable attribute.

I promise I will donate 100 points as soon as my reputation reaches 10k to the kind soul that stoops to pointing out the bug before the downvotes start pouring in.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, the second half of the question did not make it in the first try. I hope the question is now readable.

Comment: The code as indented won't run. Please fix.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the comment. Thank you, glglgl!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to name the getter too:

```
name = property(fget=name, fset=set_name)
```

or simply

```
name = property(name, set_name)
```

See the [`property` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

The `@` decorator syntax is simply syntactic sugar; the following form:

```
@decorator_expression
def function_name(...):
    ...
```

is executed as:

```
def function_name(...):
    ...
function_name = decorator_expression(function_name)
```

Note how the `decorator_expression` part is treated as a callable with the function being passed in as the first argument. A `property()` is no different in that respect.

After the first property is defined for `name`, you have a *new* object `name` in your class namespace, the `property` object. That object has a `.setter()` method, which just returns the property with the setter replaced by the new function passed in.

Thus, the syntax `@name.setter` results in the `.setter()` method on the existing `property` instance being called, and that method returns a property with it's setter being replaced.

So, you could also spell your explicit property creator thus:

```
name = property(name)
name = name.setter(set_name)
```

Your version simply replaced the `name` property (defined with a getter) with one defining only a setter, the two having no relation otherwise.

Comment: Or, to be closer to the `@name.setter` form, `name = name.setter(set_name)`.

Comment: @delnan: I was getting there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

getters and setters are kinda pointless in python, unless they are actually doing things.

```
class kid:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name


>>>bill = kid('bill')
>>>bill.name = 'johnny' #is good enough
>>>bill.name
johnny
>>>bill.job = 'student'
>>>bill.job
student
```

Comment: True, but that wasn't the question.